# Upload Image and Send some text with it POST method in android app and php server site

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

**IT IS SELF ANSWER QUESTION**

I want to send some texts with my image which want to upload, I know that Apache HttpClient multipart is deprecated. so I want to do this with HTTPUrlConnection . here my code below, please help.

Comment: You did not describe whats working and what not. Nor are there any questions.

Comment: I just dont know how add post request to server with image upload request together in httpUrlConnection method! Each of them alone work fine but I dont know how to do these both together.

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to write the code for it in both android and php.

Comment: If you google around  or just read `android` pages on this site you will find examples ecery day again.

Comment: I search for it but all are with Apache HttpClient library that is deprecated.

Comment: $_FILES and $_POST requests together, how is the android code with HTTPUrlConnection?!!

Comment: Examples plenty on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: I just rewrite my code (the correct one). hope help others with same trouble. I want to send an image with username and token, it is gonna like this in android and php :

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    int fbyte,buffersize,cbuffer;
    int maxbuffer=1024*1024;
    final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try{
        String sfile = params[1].toString();
        File f=new File(sfile);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        URL url=new URL(params[0].toString());
        HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-Alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("ENCType", "multipart/form-data");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        con.setRequestProperty("imagefile", sfile);
        DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());


        // upload image :
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imagefile\"; filename=\"" + sfile + "\""+ lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        fbyte=fis.available();
        buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
        byte[] buffer=new byte[buffersize];
        cbuffer=fis.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
        while(cbuffer>0){
            dos.write(buffer,0,buffersize);
            fbyte=fis.available();
            buffersize=Math.min(fbyte, maxbuffer);
            cbuffer=fis.read(buffer,0,buffersize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        String Username = "my username";
        String Token    = "my token";

        //write username :
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens+ boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\";" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + Username + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        //write token :
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens+ boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\";" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + Token + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        if(con.getResponseCode()==200){
            fis.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }

    }catch(final Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    return "";
}// end doInBackground()
```

php side :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

$target_path = "upload/". basename( $_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

echo "username: ".$username." and token: ".$token;
```